# How to automatically set the time-series value for the current date in Google Docs Script?

Tags: google-apps-script

I have the following rows and columns. The value is coming from a simple API call. Is it possible to store that value for the current day and keep the previously stored value automatically? Right now, I simply copy paste the value for the day, but if I forget to update it, I might miss some data.

```
26/06/2019  0.01887913
27/06/2019  
28/06/2019  
29/06/2019
```

For example, for 27/06/2019, each time I open the doc, it would update the value if it is 27th, but then if I load the doc the next day, it will not be touching the 27th any more and will be updating the 28th.

Comment: This is financial data, so I think I will query the daily close of the OHCL data for each date.

Comment: The question is too broad  and vague. If you just want to know, is it possible to automatically copy paste data everyday, Yes, it's possible.

Comment: Ok :) How? Can I take the value from a cell and set it to the cell next to the date?

Comment: `Can I take the value from a cell and set it to the cell next to the date?` Yes. `How?` Too broad. Insufficient information too. Figure it out. Start by recording a macro. Start learning js. And if there's a specific problem, show your code as a [mre].

Comment: Well, I will find the solution and share it here. So others can benefit, probably a lot more constructive than your obstructive approach.

Comment: Ok````````.````````